# How to solve File was not uploaded due to an unknown error in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel

I am stuck here, How to solve this "File was not uploaded due to an unknown error in Laravel 5.3"?
When I upload more than three images than I face this error but when I upload one or two images then it goes fine. Images are saving in folder and database also.

```
FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:
The file "boy-clipart.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

Here is the code:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('path')) {
     $files = $request->file('path');
     foreach($files as $file){

         $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

         $picture = rand(10,100)."-".$filename;
         $file->move(public_path('product-images'), $picture,filesize(public_path('product-images')), null, true);
         $productImage = new ProductImages();
         $productImage->product_id = $product->id;
         $productImage->path = $picture;
         $productImage->sortorder = $sortorder;
         $productImage->save();
     }

 }
```

[image: error]

Please help.

Comment: Where is that error coming from? What's the full stack trace look like?

Comment: while upload the image

Comment: are you using any plugin to upload the files? Provide your code snippets.

Comment: How big are the files? How is your max_upload_size set in php.ini and in your webserver? Many questions. Please provide code to analyze.

Comment: I am using  $file->move @AlankarMore

Comment: File size is not an issue @dns_nx

Comment: Please provide your code snippets.

Comment: Please see my code now @AlankarMore

Comment: As per my understanding move method has two arguments, but as per your code, you are passing 4. Kindly check document here. https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_move

Comment: But file are uploading and filename also saving in database...very strange. @AlankarMore

Comment: Instead of boy-clipart.png this file try to upload any other file as 3rd file may be the image is corrupted.

Comment: "As per my understanding move method has two arguments"
Not worked @AlankarMore

Comment: "Instead of boy-clipart.png this file try to upload any other file as 3rd file may be the image is corrupted" not an issue @AlankarMore