# Laravel 8 how to use setter method to upload an image

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I was using the old Laravel setter method in the model to upload an icon image when creating a new Category

```
    class Category extends Model
    {
        public function setIconAttribute($value)
        { 
               $fileName = 'Icon_'. $this->name .'_'.rand(11111,99999).'.'.$value->getClientOriginalExtension();  
               $destinationPath = public_path('images/Icon');
               $value->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
               $this->attributes['icon'] = $fileName;
        } 
    }
```

and it was working fine ,
now I am upgrading to the new laravel 8.77 setter

```
protected  function icon(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make (
        get: fn ($value) => asset('images/Icon/'.$value),
        set: function ($value) {
            $fileName = 'Icon_'.rand(11111,99999).'.'.$value->getClientOriginalExtension(); // renameing image  
            $destinationPath = public_path('images/Icon');
            $value->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
            return $fileName;
        }
    );
}
```

and it gets me an error

> The file "Finishe_30574.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

so first how to fix this error

and how to add the attribute name ($this->name) in the file name - in the new Laravel-8 setter like the old way

```
   $fileName = 'Icon_'. $this->name .'_'.rand(11111,99999).'.'.$value->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

because adding ($this->name) in the new setter way getts an error

Comment: You asked this question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497610/laravel-8-how-to-use-setter-to-upload-an-image and were instructed to edit your question to include more details. Is there a reason you felt the need to ask it again without really updating anything?

Comment: I already added more info to the question - I just don't get what part is/are missing - could you please provide help

Comment: The questions side-by-side are nearly identical, aside from "now I am upgrading to the new way" vs "and it was working fine , now I am upgrading to the new way". My comment is more related to you deleting that question and re-asking it; don't do that. When you're asked to edit your question, do that; **do not delete and repost it**.

Comment: I updated the first question - and it is still closed - so I did what I do - however sorry for that

Comment: It's alright; just be aware that doing that is generally discouraged. Moving on; have you checked your error against other questions on Stackoverflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964907/laravel-the-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417690/the-file-image-jpg-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error-in-laravel-while-u, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066798/how-to-solve-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error-in-laravel-5-3; looks like you're not the first one to encounter this error.

Comment: yes, I did - but my case is different - it works fine for me , only when using it with the new Laravel way it does not work

Comment: Ok, well if none of those questions/answers worked for you, and you feel it is an issue with Laravel 9, consider searching for and/or opening an Issue on Laravel's GitHub page: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues.

Comment: ok , i will thanks